# Prolog why is there a redo here?

Tags: recursion, prolog

So, I have this code:

```
shuffle([],[],[]).
shuffle([], Shuffled, Rest):-
    listReverse(Rest, RestRes),
    shuffle(RestRes, Shuffled, []).
shuffle([A|[]], [A|Shuffled], Rest):-
    shuffle(Rest, Shuffled, []).
shuffle([A, B|List], [A|Shuffled], Rest):-
    shuffle(List, Shuffled, [B|Rest]).
```

And helper:

```
listReverse(L, R):-
    listReverse(L,[],R).
listReverse([H|T],A,R):-    
    listReverse(T,[H|A],R).  
listReverse([],A,A).
```

It works fine, when I call:

```
shuffle([1,2,3], X, []),
```

I get: `X = [1,3,2]` but then there is a questionmark "?", and if I press ";", then prolog redoes the statement, setting `X = [1,3,2]` and returns the same thing again, over and over.

Why is this, and how can I fix it?

It looks like this:

```
X = [1,3,2,4] ? ;
     77   64  Redo: skyffla([1,2,3,4],[1,3,2,4]) ? 
     78   65  Redo: shuffle([1,2,3,4],[1,3,2,4],[]) ? 
     79   66  Redo: shuffle([3,4],[3,2,4],[2]) ? 
     80   67  Redo: shuffle([],[2,4],[4,2]) ? 
     85   68  Redo: shuffle([2,4],[2,4],[]) ? 
     86   69  Redo: shuffle([],[4],[4]) ? 
     90   70  Redo: shuffle([4],[4],[]) ? 
     91   71  Redo: shuffle([],[],[]) ? 
     92   72  Call: listReverse([],_2668) ? 
     93   73  Call: listReverse([],[],_2693) ? 
     93   73  Exit: listReverse([],[],[]) ? 
     92   72  Exit: listReverse([],[]) ? 
     94   72  Call: shuffle([],_2604,[]) ? 
     94   72  Exit: shuffle([],[],[]) ? 
     91   71  Exit: shuffle([],[],[]) ? 
     90   70  Exit: shuffle([4],[4],[]) ? 
     86   69  Exit: shuffle([],[4],[4]) ? 
     85   68  Exit: shuffle([2,4],[2,4],[]) ? 
     80   67  Exit: shuffle([],[2,4],[4,2]) ? 
     79   66  Exit: shuffle([3,4],[3,2,4],[2]) ? 
     78   65  Exit: shuffle([1,2,3,4],[1,3,2,4],[]) ? 
     77   64  Exit: skyffla([1,2,3,4],[1,3,2,4]) ? 

X = [1,3,2,4] ? ;
```

Comment: Just a couple of neutral comments: `[A|[]]` is the same as just `[A]`. And Prolog has a built-in `reverse` predicate, so you don't need `listReverse`.

Comment: I think you need to sort out your base case where the first argument is `[]`. Even the query, `shuffle([], A, [])` runs infinitely, and it's because your first two clauses continually succeed on `shuffle([], [], [])`. The recursion in the second clause causes it to do so infinitely. If in your second clause, you enforce that the 3rd argument is not `[]` (*e.g.*, add `Rest = [_|_],` as the first line in the body), then it won't give you infinite results. But you'll find your shuffling doesn't give you all possible shuffled results because of other flaws in the algorithm.

Comment: Here's a simple fix: **Use `permutation/2`**, a library predicate offered by SICStus Prolog, SWI Prolog, and many others...

Answer (score 0):

How about the following program?

```
shuffle([], Shuffled, Shuffled).

shuffle( List, [X | Shuffled], Rest):-

    list_member_get( List, X, List2 ),

    shuffle(List2, Shuffled, Rest).

list_member_get( [X | Rest], X, Rest ).

list_member_get( [First | Rest], X, [First | Rest2] ) :-
    list_member_get( Rest, X, Rest2 ).
```

Result

```
1 ?- shuffle([1,2,3], X, []).
X = [1, 2, 3] ;
X = [1, 3, 2] ;
X = [2, 1, 3] ;
X = [2, 3, 1] ;
X = [3, 1, 2] ;
X = [3, 2, 1] ;
false.

2 ?- shuffle([1,2,3,4], X, []).
X = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;
X = [1, 2, 4, 3] ;
X = [1, 3, 2, 4] ;
X = [1, 3, 4, 2] ;
X = [1, 4, 2, 3] ;
X = [1, 4, 3, 2] ;
X = [2, 1, 3, 4] ;
X = [2, 1, 4, 3] ;
X = [2, 3, 1, 4] ;
X = [2, 3, 4, 1] ;
X = [2, 4, 1, 3] ;
X = [2, 4, 3, 1] ;
X = [3, 1, 2, 4] ;
X = [3, 1, 4, 2] ;
X = [3, 2, 1, 4] ;
X = [3, 2, 4, 1] ;
X = [3, 4, 1, 2] ;
X = [3, 4, 2, 1] ;
X = [4, 1, 2, 3] ;
X = [4, 1, 3, 2] ;
X = [4, 2, 1, 3] ;
X = [4, 2, 3, 1] ;
X = [4, 3, 1, 2] ;
X = [4, 3, 2, 1] ;
false.
```

Comment: I don't see a difference of your code and the widely-available `lists:permutation/2`...